# find amount paid and pending

Tags: mysql

i am a new bee in Mysql Db can you help me to getting ginven output from my current table .

Please check given link for table structur and output

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OchCs.png

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Hint : you will need group by, sum and if statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, `SUM`, And `CASE` (or IF):

```
SELECT Buyer, TotalAmount, PaidAmount, TotalAmount-PaidAmount BalanceAmount
FROM (
  SELECT Buyer, 
    SUM(Amount) TotalAmount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PaidStatus = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) PaidAmount
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY Buyer
  ) t
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57f0d/1)